# Promise not working: code is executed while task still not done

Tags: javascript

Edit: can you spot the bugs in this poker game? it's driving me crazy. the promise isn't working. plus poker is played with max 9 players. I managed to have 10 players although I specified the number of players. I don't know what's going on. Can somebody help me?

```
function playerActs(i, s) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`player ${i+1} took ${(s/1000).toFixed(2)} secs to decide`);
    resolve('finished');
  });
}

async function round() {

  let hasEveryoneSpoken = false;
  let hasEveryoneChecked = false;
  let isEveryoneAllIn = false;
  let stopBettingRound = false;

  let nbPlayers = 9;

  let i = 0;
  while (!stopBettingRound) {

    let delay = (Math.random() * 1000 * 5);

    // wait until the player take a decision
    let res = await setTimeout(playerActs, delay, i, delay);
    console.log(res);

    // dummy condition to exit loop
    if (i == nbPlayers) hasEveryoneSpoken = true;

    stopBettingRound =
      hasEveryoneSpoken || hasEveryoneChecked || isEveryoneAllIn;

    i++;
  }
}

round();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `setInterval` like that because as with Promises, it doesn't block code execution, so the code falls straight through to your call to `resolve`.

I would suggest that you refactor the entire count-down logic into its own function that also wraps a Promise that you can `await` for.

That said, I also don't see any logic yet to allow you to *cancel* the countdown if the user proceeds with their next move while you're waiting.

Comment: at the moment I'm focused on blocking execution of the program while a human has to interact :)

Comment: that's the thing - you *can't* block execution.    You could `await` a Promise where that promise's resolution depends on  _either_ the timer to expire (in which case you could `reject`) or for your user input to occur.